# Pandas: Replicate Excel COUNTIF using 2 dataframes and using a wildcard?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, countif

I am working on a script which automates some of repetitive data transformation/cleaning I often do within excel, I have been able to make good gains however I am gotten stuck up until this point:

I have brought in all my relevant dataframes and done some filtering and other cleaning. For this part of my script, I have created 2 dataframes, df2 is my newly created unique list of product ID's based on df1, my "master list" containing the product ID's as well as their procurement codes.

My end result is to count the number of times the product ID has a P, A, X leading procurement code (these would be separated into their own columns) however I am not sure how I can do this across two different data frames.

Sample of made-up data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ProductID': ["12441","44123","77880","12345","33445","77565","34354","77880","33445", "12345", "12441", "12441","12441","44123"], 
"ProcCode":["P34","P35","P67","P67","X77","P34","P35","P34","X77","P35","A55","P34","P35","A55"]})
```

```
   ProductID ProcCode
0      12441      P34
1      44123      P35
2      77880      P67
3      12345      P67
4      33445      X77
5      77565      P34
6      34354      P35
7      77880      P34
8      33445      X77
9      12345      P35
10     12441      A55
11     12441      P34
12     12441      P35
13     44123      A55
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ProductID": ["12441","44123","77880","12345","33445","77565"]})
```

```
  ProductID
0     12441
1     44123
2     77880
3     12345
4     33445
5     77565
```

After applying a countif style code I should produce the following dataframe:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"ProductID":["12441","44123","77880","12345","33445","77565"], "CountofPCode":[3,1,2,3,0,1],"CountofXCode":[0,0,0,0,2,0]})
```

```
  ProductID  CountofPCode  CountofXCode
0     12441             3             0
1     44123             1             0
2     77880             2             0
3     12345             3             0
4     33445             0             2
5     77565             1             0
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code used to produce your sample DataFrames? There are several issues.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Thanks, I've updated them.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be something like:

```
out = (
    # Group by the ProductID and First letter. Get Value Counts.
    df1.groupby([df1.ProductID, df1.ProcCode.str[0]]).value_counts()
       .unstack(-2)  # Unstack the first letter.
       .groupby('ProductID').sum()  # Group by ProductID. Get Sum.
)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
ProcCode     A    P    X
ProductID
12345      0.0  2.0  0.0
12441      1.0  3.0  0.0
33445      0.0  0.0  2.0
34354      0.0  1.0  0.0
44123      1.0  1.0  0.0
77565      0.0  1.0  0.0
77880      0.0  2.0  0.0
```

---

Another:

```
df1['ProcCodePrefix'] = df1.ProcCode.str[0]
out = df1.pivot_table(
    index='ProductID',
    columns='ProcCodePrefix',
    values='ProcCodePrefix',
    aggfunc='count',
    fill_value=0,
)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
ProcCodePrefix  A  P  X
ProductID
12345           0  2  0
12441           1  3  0
33445           0  0  2
34354           0  1  0
44123           1  1  0
77565           0  1  0
77880           0  2  0
```

Cleaning this up to match your output:

```
out.columns.name = None
out.columns = "Countof" + out.columns + "Code"
out = out.reset_index()
print(out)
```

Output:

```
  ProductID  CountofACode  CountofPCode  CountofXCode
0     12345             0             2             0
1     12441             1             3             0
2     33445             0             0             2
3     34354             0             1             0
4     44123             1             1             0
5     77565             0             1             0
6     77880             0             2             0
```

Comment: This looks exactly what I'm looking for. Had no idea I could replicate a pivot table within Python.